# JQuery on click event not working inside dropdown menu with hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, typeahead.js

I have an autocomplete dropdown using twitter-typeahead as follows:

```
$('#Data').typeahead(
   {
        displayKey: 'description',
        source: myData.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: [
              '<div class="empty-message">',
                <a class="js-not-found" href="#">No results found</a>,
              '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function (data) {
                return '<span>' + data.description + '</span>';
            }
          }
    }
);
```

When no results are found the dropdown display a link. I have wired this to a Jquery on click handler as below but when I click the link it just reloads the page?

```
$(".js-not-found").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // some stuff
});
```

The event handler works fine if I have a normal link outside of the dropdown as follows `<a class="js-not-found" href="#">No results found</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is not inside the DOM when you attach the event. For dynamically generated elements you should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Can you try :

```
$(document).on('click','.js-not-found', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // some stuff
});
```

For better performance it's recommanded to use the direct ancestor inside the DOM of the generated element :

```
$(".container").on('click','.js-not-found', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `delegate()` function you can click on dynamically generated HTML elements that are not in your DOM.

Example:

```
$(document).delegate('.js-not-found', 'click', function()
{
 e.preventDefault();
 //your code
});
```

or you can use `on()` as

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-not-found', function()
{
// your code
});
```